# what is the practical difference between calling these given methods in "method-overriding" in java?

Tags: java, overriding

```
class A {

    public void method() {
        System.out.println("This is the method of A");
    }
}

public class B extends A {

    public void method() {
        System.out.println("This is the method of B");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        A a = new B();
        a.method();

        B b = new B();
        b.method();

    }
}
```

I know the working flow, as at the run time B's object is going to be created so B's method will call. 
I know here Polymorphism is used(method overriding, I want to know its practical use).

I want to know what is the difference between a.method(); and b.method();
How reference a is better than using reference b?
I am going to get the same results.
And what is the difference between them Practical use wise?

Thanks!

Comment: You should check out the wikipedia article on polymorphism

Answer (score 0):

Consider a scenario in which you have a `List<A>`, and you wish to call `method` for each instance in the list. Some of these instances are instances of class B, but others may be of other classes that extend A. Polymorphism would allow you to write code that doesn't know class B even exists, and still execute `method` of class `B`.

Answer (score 0):

For an example this simple, there's really no benefit of one over the other.

But imagine a situation where you were calling someone else's code, and it was going to return something of type `A`. Here, the polymorphism would allow that code actually to return you something of type `B`, with a customised  implementation of the method. The right method would get called, and you would never need to worry about the fact that it was a subclass that had been returned.